# Nested IF statements with 3 conditions in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three conditions in ONE cell:

1. IF A1 is smaller than 22000 write 3.600.
2. IF A1 is bigger than 64000 write 9600.
3. IF A1 is in between 22000 AND 64000 calculate A1+B2

I don't really get it working…

This is what I have for now:
IF(OR(A1>64000;A1<22000);(A1+B1);IF(A1>64000;9600;))

Somehow the (A1<22000;3600;) is missing and won't fit anywhere... Totally lost.

Can someone help?

Comment: try it again now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(a1<22000,3600,IF(a1<=64000,a1+b2,9600))
```

Comment: There seems something wrong in the second part. IF should contain 2 arguments (True, False) but contains 3 in your example. Doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: Odd. Someone edited my question. Don't know if that or myself introduced bug. Try the re-edit.

Comment: @JGFMK you can see the edits by clicking the edited *** ago link and side-by-side markdown. Seems like the first edit was just cosmetic to make the answer more readable.